# Formatting a text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using this function to change the content of a div box by clicking on an external link.
The function looks as below:

```
<!--
 function ReplaceContentInContainer(id,content) {
 var container = document.getElementById(id);
 container.innerHTML = content;
 }
 //-->
```

the HTML is:

```
<li><a href="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer('pippo','<span style="font-size: 14px; font-color:red;">pluto</span>')"> Wedding Receptions</a></li>
```

When I run the code the link will appear like this:

> pluto')"> Wedding Receptions

and, of course, if clicked on doesn't change the content in the box.
I have tried to adjust the code from almost every corner. 
Any suggestion on this matter? Where I was wrong?
Cheers
Valter

Comment: Try escaping the double quotes inside for the second parameter, like: '<span style=\"font-size... edit: never mind, don't work

Comment: make all double quotes inside the href="" to single quote, that will help

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by your inner double quotes in `style=""`

They can't be double quotes because you're already using double quotes in `href=""`, which is parsed as HTML.

They can't be single quotes because you're already using single quotes in `'<span>...'`, which is parsed as a JavaScript string.

You can used **escaped single quotes** instead: `\'`. This means it won't be parsed as either HTML or a JS string delimiter, but rather as JS string content, which is what you want.

`<li><a href="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer('pippo','<span style=\'font-size: 14px; font-color:red;\'>pluto</span>')"> Wedding Receptions</a></li>`